# Issue with importing external buffer into Vulkan in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, vulkan, android-mediacodec

I am trying to display a image in Android 10 using Vulkan. The pipeline looks like this

*MediaCodec -> ImageReader -> AHardwareBuffer (Passed to the Vulkan context) -> Map to Vulkan -> display it using Vulkan API's*

In the Native CPP layer, the following is done in the Vulkan Context for importing the hardwarebuffer:
*Find Properties Of AHardwareBuffer -> Create VkImage -> **Create Device Memory (Dedicated memory)** -> Map the buffer to VkImage -> Sample using YUVSampler*

The issue is that the 'Create Device Memory' is the step for which the Vulkan Validation layer shows the error. It complains that the format is not supported. Please note that I am using an external format (SPEC allows this) so that the format handling is opaque. 
This is not working right now and I only see a black frame everytime. Could anyone please review this? What am I missing in the logic for importing a AHardwareBuffer into the Vulkan Context.

Why external format? Well because I cannot control the output of Decoder on different devices and would like some opaque method of handling it.

Also, I am using the following settings for creating the ImageReader

```
ImageReader.newInstance(1920, 1080, ImageFormat.PRIVATE, MAX_IMAGE_SIZE + 1,
    HardwareBuffer.USAGE_GPU_SAMPLED_IMAGE);
```

The code in Vulkan, from the point I receive the AHardwareBuffer to the API that validation layer thinks is causing an issue is below. I have tried to only keep the relevant code to the mapping here.

```
VkAndroidHardwareBufferFormatPropertiesANDROID hardwareBufferFormat{
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ANDROID_HARDWARE_BUFFER_FORMAT_PROPERTIES_ANDROID,
    .pNext = nullptr,
};

VkAndroidHardwareBufferPropertiesANDROID hardwareBufferProperties{
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ANDROID_HARDWARE_BUFFER_PROPERTIES_ANDROID,
    .pNext = &hardwareBufferFormat,
};

/* Find the properties of AHardwareBuffer that is to be imported */
vkGetAndroidHardwareBufferPropertiesANDROID(mLogicalDevice, buffer, &hardwareBufferProperties);

// mTexture.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
VkImage Image_local;
VkExternalFormatANDROID externalFormatAndroid{
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_FORMAT_ANDROID,
    .pNext = nullptr,
    .externalFormat = hardwareBufferFormat.externalFormat,
};

VkExternalMemoryImageCreateInfo externalMemoryImageCreateInfo{
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO,
    .pNext = &externalFormatAndroid,
    .handleTypes = VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_ANDROID_HARDWARE_BUFFER_BIT_ANDROID,
};

VkImageCreateInfo imageCreateInfo{
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO,
    .pNext = &externalMemoryImageCreateInfo,
    .flags = 0,
    .imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D,
    .format = VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED,
    .extent = {1920, 1080, 1},
    .mipLevels = 1,
    .arrayLayers = hardwareBufferDesc.layers,
    .samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT,
    .tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL,
    .usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT,
    .sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE,
    .queueFamilyIndexCount = 0,
    .pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr,
    .initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
};

vkCreateImage(mLogicalDevice, &imageCreateInfo, nullptr, &Image_local);

VkImportAndroidHardwareBufferInfoANDROID hardwareBufferInfo{
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMPORT_ANDROID_HARDWARE_BUFFER_INFO_ANDROID,
    .pNext = nullptr,
    .buffer = buffer};

VkMemoryDedicatedAllocateInfo memoryDedicatedAllocateInfo{
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_DEDICATED_ALLOCATE_INFO,
    .pNext = &hardwareBufferInfo,
    .image = Image_local,
    .buffer = VK_NULL_HANDLE,
};

uint32_t mem_index = GetMemoryType(hardwareBufferProperties.memoryTypeBits, 0);
VkMemoryAllocateInfo memoryAllocateInfo{
    .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO,
    .pNext = &memoryDedicatedAllocateInfo,
    .allocationSize = hardwareBufferProperties.allocationSize,
    .memoryTypeIndex = mem_index,
};

/* So this API here does not return any erros, however the validation layer says that the format
 * is not supported. I am using an external Format, so assuming that this should not complain.
 */
vkAllocateMemory(mLogicalDevice, &memoryAllocateInfo, nullptr, &mTexture.deviceMemory)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer, but from reading some other code which does this and the spec, it looks like hardwareBufferFormat.format can be VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED, but can also be a valid VK_FORMAT which can be written into VkImageCreateInfo. Only if that member is VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED do you need to use the externalFormat member.

Comment: @LewisGordon In my case the format is VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED. So I have to use externalFormat. The externalFormat is a non zero large value.