# Displaying texture coming from ImageReader in Vulkan

Tags: android, c++, exoplayer, vulkan, decoder

I'd like to know if it is possible to display the contents of a texture coming from an ImageReader using vulkan.

This is how a create the ImageReader

`mReader = ImageReader.newInstance(1920, 1080, ImageFormat.PRIVATE, MAX_IMAGE_SIZE + 1);`

**The image contains secure content**.  On the Vulkan side, I try to obtain the hardware buffer and instantiate an image, but the validation layers complains:

> (ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 0 - vkAllocateMemory: The AHardwareBuffer_Desc's format ( 2141391878 ) and/or usage ( 0x20002900 ) are not compatible with Vulkan. The Vulkan spec states: If buffer is not NULL, it must be a valid Android hardware buffer object with AHardwareBuffer_Desc::format and AHardwareBuffer_Desc::usage compatible with Vulkan as described in Android Hardware Buffers. (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkImportAndroidHardwareBufferInfoANDROID-buffer-01881)

The problem is that the AHardwareBuffer is not created by me, is created by the ImageReader class.

Here is the code on the C++ side:

```
VkAndroidHardwareBufferFormatPropertiesANDROID hardwareBufferFormat{
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ANDROID_HARDWARE_BUFFER_FORMAT_PROPERTIES_ANDROID,
        .pNext = nullptr,
    };

    VkAndroidHardwareBufferPropertiesANDROID hardwareBufferProperties{
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ANDROID_HARDWARE_BUFFER_PROPERTIES_ANDROID,
        .pNext = &hardwareBufferFormat,
    };

    vkGetAndroidHardwareBufferPropertiesANDROID(mLogicalDevice, buffer, &hardwareBufferProperties);

    LOGD("Size %lu MemType %s format 0x%X extFormat 0x%lX flags 0x%X",
         hardwareBufferProperties.allocationSize,
         GetMemoryTypeString(hardwareBufferProperties.memoryTypeBits).c_str(),
         hardwareBufferFormat.format, hardwareBufferFormat.externalFormat,
         hardwareBufferFormat.formatFeatures);
    LOGD("Flags: \n%s", GetFeatureFlagBitsString(hardwareBufferFormat.formatFeatures).c_str());

    LOGD("AHardwareBuffer format in vulkan is %d", hardwareBufferFormat.format);

    //VkFormat fmt = vk_format_from_android(hardwareBufferFormat.format, 0 );
    AHardwareBuffer_Desc hardwareBufferDesc{};
    AHardwareBuffer_describe(buffer, &hardwareBufferDesc);

    // Width and Height must be same as per spec
    mTexture.width = hardwareBufferDesc.width;
    mTexture.height = hardwareBufferDesc.height;
    mTexture.mipLevels = 1;
    mTexture.imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

    LOGD("Image width x height %dx%d", mTexture.width, mTexture.height);

    VkExternalFormatANDROID externalFormatAndroid{
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_FORMAT_ANDROID,
        .pNext = nullptr,
        .externalFormat = hardwareBufferFormat.externalFormat,
    };

    VkExternalMemoryImageCreateInfo externalMemoryImageCreateInfo{
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO,
        .pNext = &externalFormatAndroid,
        .handleTypes = VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_ANDROID_HARDWARE_BUFFER_BIT_ANDROID,
    };

    VkAndroidHardwareBufferUsageANDROID hardwareBufferUsage {};
    VkImageFormatProperties2 properties {}; 
    VkPhysicalDeviceImageFormatInfo2 deviceImageFormat {};

    VkImageCreateInfo imageCreateInfo{
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO,
        .pNext = &externalMemoryImageCreateInfo,
        .flags = 0,
        .imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D,
        .format = VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED,
        .extent = {mTexture.width, mTexture.height, 1},
        .mipLevels = mTexture.mipLevels,
        .arrayLayers = hardwareBufferDesc.layers,
        .samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT,
        .tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL,
        .usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT,
        .sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE,
        .queueFamilyIndexCount = 0,
        .pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr,
        .initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED,
    };

    CHECK_VK_RESULT(vkCreateImage(mLogicalDevice, &imageCreateInfo, nullptr, &mTexture.image));

    // AHardwareBuffer_Desc::format and AHardwareBuffer_Desc::usage must be valid and compatible
    // with Vulkan
    VkImportAndroidHardwareBufferInfoANDROID hardwareBufferInfo{
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMPORT_ANDROID_HARDWARE_BUFFER_INFO_ANDROID,
        .pNext = nullptr,
        .buffer = buffer};

    VkMemoryDedicatedAllocateInfo memoryDedicatedAllocateInfo{
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_DEDICATED_ALLOCATE_INFO,
        .pNext = &hardwareBufferInfo,
        .image = mTexture.image,
        .buffer = VK_NULL_HANDLE,
    };

    /* TODO: Double check memoryTypeBits and using VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT */
    uint32_t mem_index = GetMemoryType(hardwareBufferProperties.memoryTypeBits,  0);
    if (mem_index < 0) {
        LOGE("Could not find matching memory type!");
        return VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED;
    }

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo memoryAllocateInfo{
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO,
        .pNext = &memoryDedicatedAllocateInfo,
        .allocationSize = hardwareBufferProperties.allocationSize,
        .memoryTypeIndex = mem_index};

    // THIS IS WHERE THE VALIDATION THROWS ERROR
    CHECK_VK_RESULT(
        vkAllocateMemory(mLogicalDevice, &memoryAllocateInfo, nullptr, &mTexture.deviceMemory))
```

I understand am dealing with private memory, the spec though seems to require (even with unknown memory formats) that the AHardwareBuffer_desc format must be something that has an equivalent in Vulkan; it seems to me that's unreasonable since in this situation the format could be proprietary.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you can provide usage to `newInstance` otherwise this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314012/issue-with-importing-external-buffer-into-vulkan-in-android

Comment: Possibly relates to https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/issues/1935